# How to update jQuery in drupal7

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to update my drupal jquery1.4 to jquery1.8. I tried by using following way.

```
  function oxavd_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  //We define the path of our new jquery core file
  //assuming we are using the minified version 1.8
  $jquery_path = drupal_get_path('theme','oxavd') . '/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js';

 //We duplicate the important information from the Drupal one
 $javascript[$jquery_path] = $javascript['misc/jquery.js'];
 //..and we update the information that we care about
 $javascript[$jquery_path]['version'] = '1.8.0';
 $javascript[$jquery_path]['data'] = $jquery_path;

 //Then we remove the Drupal core version
 unset($javascript['misc/jquery.js']);
}
```

I referred this from [here](http://www.rgracia.com/content/blog/may/12/2013/how-update-jquery-your-drupal-7-theme)

But this wasn't worked for me.
It shows version 1.4.4

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery Update module](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update).

Also see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download